# How to configure DNS on Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, dns

I use Fedora 16 and I'm trying to configure the DNS but it is not working. I  followed this tutorial:

http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_16&p=dns&f=1

My IP is 172.31.50.86, I want to named domain as ccxte.com

Can someone show me a config of named.conf file and another file?

Comment: are you trying to point the domain to that ip address? is this an active external domain name thats pointing to your server in a different location?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to propagate this DNS Record to other machines (i.e., acting as a DNS server) from this server, or do you have this registered with a domain registrar, and have it pointed to this IP address?

Most people would be using the latter, unless it is for services existing on an intranet.

If it is the latter, you can add it into your /etc/hosts

Your /etc/hosts can simply look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost ccxte.com
::1         localhost ccxte.com
```

Comment: Note, the second line exists only for ipv6 compatibility, and can be discarded if you're using ipv4-only.

Answer (score -1):

take some others better tutorial from ubuntu official website and don't forget to do install apt-install I have one a domain name that yet configured.

Regards,